# web policy agent not redirecting to OpenAM URl

Tags: web, policy, agent, openam, opendj

I am working on OpenAM  for the first time, i am  following below link
https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/getting-started.

i followed all the steps but when i click the agent URL i am not redirected to OPenAM URL. i am getting message :"it works".

agent URl:http://localhost:8088/

openAM URL:http://localhost:8080/OpenAM/

Answer (score 1):

Using "localhost" is a recipe for trouble. OpenAM uses cookies, and needs a real FQDN to function properly. Note that guide that you reference uses "openam.example.com" when setting up OpenAM.

Please redo your installation using a proper FQDN.  This may not be your problem, but you should fix that issue first before going further.